Having trouble compiling FnF source code using HaxeFlixel
`
source/psychlua/CallbackHandler. hx:55: characters 18-33 : Class<llua. Lua_helper> has no field sendErrorsToLua
export/release/windows/haxe/ApplicationMain.hx:153: characters 5-36 :
... Called from macro here
C: /HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flxanimate/3, 0,4/flxanimate/frames/FlxAnimateFrames. hx: 142: characters 21-27 : Field concat sho
ld be declared with 'override' since it is inherited from superclass flixel. graphics. frames. FlxAtlasFrames
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flxanimate/3, 0,4/flxanimate/frames/FlxAnimateFrames. hx: 142: characters 21-27 : Field concat ove
rides parent class with different or incomplete type
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel/5,8,0/flixel/graphics/frames/FlxAtlasFrames. hx:472: characters 18-24 : ... Base field is
defined here
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flxanimate/3, 0,4/flxanimate/frames/FlxAnimateFrames.hx: 142: characters 21-27 :
ber of function arguments
source/backend/Paths.hx:605: characters 7-18 : flxanimate. FlxAnimate has no field loadAtlasEx (Suggestion: loadAtlas)
source/objects/Character. hx:304: characters 87-101 : flxanimate. animate. FlxAnim has no field lastPlayedAnim
source/objects/Character. hx:335: characters 20-26 : flxanimate. animate. FlxAnim has no field resume

`
No matter what I have done, I keep on getting these errors
I've been wanting to make an FnF mod recently, and I'm having some trouble doing it.
I've been following longestsoloever's youtube tutorial and I have done the same thing countless times:-
These are all the instructions and videos:-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IuC8ti6_4o&list=PLfb6KneL63QuD0T0lolMvkQPQM7ZPjy9n&index=2
https://github.com/KadeDev/Kade-Engine/blob/stable/docs/building.md
I have done all the instructions and downloaded all the necessary stuff required, and yet I still receive the above errors. Is it because the dependencies are outdated?

I, and many others have no intention of visiting other web sites, or watching videos, in order to ascertain what you have, or have not, done in setting up your system and environment. Also you appear to have used at least two different tags, which implies that neither of them are the source of your problem, or relevant to your question. I have therefore replaced them both. This site is for assistance with a specific issue with your programming code, it is not here to assist you with how to setup your sytem or environment in order to use command line tools, modules or software utilities.

So no one is going to help?

You have submitted no code, only some output, and in order to assist you with a submitted code problem, we need to be able to reproduce it, and the environment in which that problem was manifested. None of that information is provided, so technically, no; noone is going to offer official help on this site.

I see, I apologize
